# Cron expression to run within time period for fixed frequency

Tags: cron

I have a following cron expression which supposed to following.

Run 4 times every day from 1am to 4am. But it seems like it's running more than that and i cannot identify a pattern. Cron expression i'm using is

```
0 1-4 * * * ?
```

Is there wrong with above expression meeting given requirement ?

Comment: The expression looks Okay. Suggest you add some echo statements to your script to troubleshoot the problem. for example `echo $(date) >>/tmp/troubleshooting.log`

Comment: Correct expression is `0 0 1-4 ? * *`